# Удалить одинаковые элементы из многомерного массива (Swift)

Tags: swift

У меня есть многомерный массив

```
var allArray = [[1,2,3], [2,3,2], [0,1,1], [1,2,3], [0,1,1]]
```

Как из массива allArray удалить все одинаковые массивы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удаления повторяющихся элементов Вы можете использовать `Set`. Пример по вопросу:

```
let allArray = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 1]]
// print(allArray) -> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 1]]

let filteredArray = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: allArray)) as! [[Int]]
// print(filteredArray) -> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [0, 1, 1]]
```